# mixing OpenGL and Interface Builder/ UI Controls - bad idea? Why? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, opengl-es, uicontrol

I've heard that OpenGL ES and standard iPhone UI controls don't play well together, but I'm wondering if anyone knows why, and what the effects are?  I'm writing an OpenGL based game, and the view is loaded from a nib file with ui controls, and it seems to work ok, but the game is really simple at this point... does using ui controls cause some kind of performance hit?

Answer (score 2):

UI events momentarily pause timers, like when scrolling a tableview. You can get around this by using the common runtime mode when creating a timer. It may slow down your rendering if you have a lot of layers because they all need to get redrawn every-time you refresh. So if your game runs at 60fps it will also redraw everything on top of the GLView, like UIImageViews, buttons etc. 60 times a second, which is a huge waste. It might not make a huge impact on your frame rate but it may make the device run hotter and drain the battery faster. Its best to draw your HUD using OpenGL, but it depends on the situation. For something that will be displayed only for a short time, like a menu I think you can get away with it.

Theres nothing wrong with it, its just wasteful.